# How to get the common index of two pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DataFrames df1 and df2 and I want to transform them in order that they keep values only for the index that are common to the 2 dataframes.

*df1*

```
                      values 1
0                            
28/11/2000          -0.055276
29/11/2000           0.027427
30/11/2000           0.066009
01/12/2000           0.012749
04/12/2000           0.113892
```

*df2*

```
                       values 2

24/11/2000            -0.004808
27/11/2000            -0.001812
28/11/2000            -0.026316
29/11/2000             0.015222
30/11/2000            -0.024480
```

become

*df1*

```
                     value 1

28/11/2000          -0.055276
29/11/2000           0.027427
30/11/2000           0.066009
```

*df2*

```
                       value 2

28/11/2000            -0.026316
29/11/2000             0.015222
30/11/2000            -0.024480
```

Comment: This can be done in a single line of code using `align()`. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78215951/19123103).

Answer (score 38):

You can use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) + [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
idx = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
print (idx)
Index(['28/11/2000', '29/11/2000', '30/11/2000'], dtype='object')
```

Alternative solution with [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html):

```
idx = np.intersect1d(df1.index, df2.index)
print (idx)
['28/11/2000' '29/11/2000' '30/11/2000']
```

---

```
df1 = df1.loc[idx]
print (df1)
            values 1
28/11/2000 -0.055276
29/11/2000  0.027427
30/11/2000  0.066009

df2 = df2.loc[idx]
```

Comment: I was wondering if you could do this with a single level of a multilevel index?

Comment: Great answer. Only a small mistake: df2 = df1.loc[idx] should be df2 = df2.loc[idx]

Answer (score 8):

```
In [352]: common = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)

In [353]: df1.loc[common]
Out[353]:
             values1
0
28/11/2000 -0.055276
29/11/2000  0.027427
30/11/2000  0.066009

In [354]: df2.loc[common]
Out[354]:
             values2
0
28/11/2000 -0.026316
29/11/2000  0.015222
30/11/2000 -0.024480
```

Answer (score 8):

And, using `isin`. `intersection` might be faster though.

```
In [286]: df1.loc[df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
Out[286]:
             values1
0
28/11/2000 -0.055276
29/11/2000  0.027427
30/11/2000  0.066009

In [287]: df2.loc[df2.index.isin(df1.index)]
Out[287]:
             values2
0
28/11/2000 -0.026316
29/11/2000  0.015222
30/11/2000 -0.024480
```

Comment: Just for everyone's reference, why `isin` is faster is explained in depth here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50881584/1003798 .


Pandas `isin` uses khash from `klib` algorithm, while numpy `in1d` or `intersect1d`  make a call to the `unique` function which increases time over a longer range of dataset.


https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib

Answer (score 4):

`reindex` + `dropna`

```
df1.reindex(df2.index).dropna()
Out[21]: 
             values1
28/11/2000 -0.055276
29/11/2000  0.027427
30/11/2000  0.066009


df2.reindex(df1.index).dropna()
Out[22]: 
             values2
28/11/2000 -0.026316
29/11/2000  0.015222
30/11/2000 -0.024480
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like

```
df1 = df1.loc[[x for x in df1.index if x in df2.index]]
df2 = df2.loc[[x for x in df2.index if x in df1.index]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The index object has some set-like properties so you simply can take the intersection as follows:

```
df1 = df1.reindex[ df1.index & df2.index ]
```

This retains the order of the first dataframe in the intersection, `df`.

Answer (score 1):

You can [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html) them with an intermediary DataFrame created with the indexes of the other DataFrame:

```
df2_indexes = pd.DataFrame(index=df2.index)
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2_indexes, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df1_indexes = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index)
df2 = pd.merge(df2, df1_indexes, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

or you can use [pd.eval](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.eval.html):

```
df2_indexes =  df2.index.values
df1 = df1[eval("df1.index in df2_indexes"]
df1_indexes = df1.index.values
df2 = df2[eval("df2.index in df1_indexes"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%timeit df1.index.intersection(df2.index)

66.5 µs ± 2.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)


from numpy.lib.arraysetops import intersect1d
%timeit np.intersect1d(df1.index,df2.index)
83.1 µs ± 7.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev.
```

of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

Answer (score 0):

I found pd.Index and set combination much faster than numpy.intersect1d as well df1.index.intersection(df2.index). Here is what I used:

`df2 = df2.loc[pd.Index(set(df1.index)&set(df2.index))]`