# Set the values out of the defined set to a given value (f.e. NaN) for a column in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, value-restriction

Having a defined set of valid values, all the pandas data frame column values out of it should be set to a given value, f.e. `NaN`. The values contained in the set and data frame can be assumed to be of numerical type.

Having the following valid values set and data frame:

```
valid = {5, 22}
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5, 1, 7, 22],'b': [12, 3 , 10, 9]})

    a   b
0   5  12
1   1   3
2   7  10
3  22   9
```

Setting the valid values on column `a` would result in:

```
     a   b
0    5  12
1  NaN   3
2  NaN  10
3   22   9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['a'].where(df['a'].isin(valid), inplace=True)

print(df)

      a   b
0   5.0  12
1   NaN   3
2   NaN  10
3  22.0   9
```

A few points to note:

- `pd.Series.isin` will work more efficiently with a `list` versus a `set`. See also [Pandas pd.Series.isin performance with set versus array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779617/pandas-pd-series-isin-performance-with-set-versus-array).
- Your series will necessarily be converted to `float` since `NaN` is considered `float`.
- The operation does not require assignment to a variable when `inplace=True` is used.

Answer (score 2):

Why not [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df.loc[~df['a'].isin(valid),'a']=pd.np.nan
```

**Example**:

```
import pandas as pd
valid = {5, 22}
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5, 1, 7, 22],'b': [12, 3 , 10, 9]})
df.loc[~df['a'].isin(valid),'a']=pd.np.nan
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      a   b
0   5.0  12
1   NaN   3
2   NaN  10
3  22.0   9
```