# Pandas: What is the difference between isin() and str.contains()?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, string-comparison

I want to know **if a specific string is present in some columns of my dataframe** (a different string for each column).
From what I understand [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) is written for dataframes but can work for Series as well, while [`str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) works better for Series.

I don't understand how I should choose between the two. (I searched for similar questions but didn't find any explanation on how to choose between the two.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`.isin` checks if each value in the column is contained in a list of arbitrary values.  Roughly equivalent to `value in [value1, value2]`.

`str.contains` checks if arbitrary values are contained in each value in the column. Roughly equivalent to `substring in large_string`.

In other words, **`.isin` works column-wise and is available for all data types. `str.contains` works element-wise and makes sense only when dealing with strings (or values that can be represented as strings).**

From the official documentation:

> [Series.isin(values)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html)
>
> Check whether values are contained in Series.
> Return a boolean Series showing whether each element in the Series
> matches an element in the passed sequence of values exactly.

> [Series.str.contains(pat, case=True, flags=0, na=nan,**
> **regex=True)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)
>
> Test if pattern or regex is contained within a
> string of a Series or Index.
>
> Return boolean Series or Index based on whether a given pattern or
> regex is contained within a string of a Series or Index.

Examples:

```
print(df)
#     a
# 0  aa
# 1  ba
# 2  ca

print(df[df['a'].isin(['aa', 'ca'])])
#     a
# 0  aa
# 2  ca

print(df[df['a'].str.contains('b')])
#     a
# 1  ba
```

Comment: It's worth noting `pd.Series.isin` exhibits [material differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779617/pandas-pd-series-isin-performance-with-set-versus-array) versus `value in container`, and may be optimized for numeric data. While `pd.Series.str.contains` is always just a Python-level loop.

Comment: it's also worth noting that .Contains, when applied to a db model, will translate into "a is in list b and a is not null".  That 2nd half cost me hours of debugging a linq query.