# how to delete rows of a df based on the column of integers in another df

Tags: pandas

I want to remove rows in df1 which have common numbers in the "0" columns of both df's

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('Displacement.txt', sep="\s", header=None)
df2= pd.read_csv('overconstraint.txt', header=None)
```

df1 (>6million rows) looks like

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0   1   ,   1   ,   1.0 ,   1.8800E-01
1   2   ,   1   ,   1.0 ,   1.8491E-01
```

df2 (>1000 rows) looks like

```
    0
0   1119933
1   1119933
2   1122062
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need specify column instead `DataFrame` by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
test=df1[~df1[0].isin(df2[0])]

#in some pandas versions is necessary convert Series to list
test=df1[~df1[0].isin(df2[0].astype(int).tolist())]
```

Solution with casting to integers:

```
test=df1[~df1[0].astype(int).isin(df2[0].astype(int))]

#in some pandas versions is necessary convert Series to list
test=df1[~df1[0].astype(int).isin(df2[0].astype(int).tolist())]
```

Comment: The name of my real data column is "0" in both df's so I used test=df1[~df1[0].isin(df2[0])] but it doesnt work. test returns the same as df1

Comment: @user9106985 - Try `df1[~df1['0'].isin(df2['0'])]`

Comment: @user9106985 - If still not working `df1[~df1['0'].astype(int).isin(df2['0'].astype(int)]`

Comment: @user9106985 - Or `df1[~df1['0'].isin(df2['0'].tolist())]` is another idea.

Comment: I have edited my original post to shown a snapshot of real data.

Answer (score 1):

Make the difference between `ref` columns:

```
>>> df1[~df1['ref'].isin(df2['ref'])]
   ref  value1
0    2      76
1    4      23
5   12      78
6   14      34
```

Comment: 11 second later... :)

Comment: Your `04:22`, my answer `04:11` ;)

Comment: Due to jet lag :-)

Comment: Hmmm, `jet leg` ? Data flow under ocean I guess ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779617/pandas-pd-series-isin-performance-with-set-versus-array