# pandas align() function : illustrative example

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I came across this line of code

```py
df1, df2 = df1.align(df2, join='inner', axis=1)
```

here `df1` and `df2` are the pandas dataframes

I know that with `align()`, you are able to perform some sort of combining of the two dataframes but I am not able to visualize how does it actually work.

I searched the documentation but could not find any illustrative example.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You are on the right track, except that `DataFrame.align` doesn't combine two dataframes, rather it **aligns** them so that the two dataframes have the same row and/or column configuration. Let's try an example:

Initialising two dataframes with some descriptive column names and toy data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [6,7,8,9]], columns=['D', 'B', 'E', 'A'], index=[1,2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[10,20,30,40], [60,70,80,90], [600,700,800,900]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], index=[2,3,4])
```

Now, let's view these data frames by themselves:

```
print(df1)
```

> ```
>    D  B  E  A
> 1  1  2  3  4
> 2  6  7  8  9
> ```

```
print(df2)
```

> ```
>      A    B    C    D
> 2   10   20   30   40
> 3   60   70   80   90
> 4  600  700  800  900
> ```

Let's align these two dataframes, aligning by columns (`axis=1`), and performing an outer join on column labels (`join='outer'`):

```
a1, a2 = df1.align(df2, join='outer', axis=1)
print(a1)
print(a2)
```

> ```
>    A  B   C  D  E
> 1  4  2 NaN  1  3
> 2  9  7 NaN  6  8
>      A    B    C    D   E
> 2   10   20   30   40 NaN
> 3   60   70   80   90 NaN
> 4  600  700  800  900 NaN
> ```

A few things to notice here:

- The columns in `df1` have been rearranged so they align with the columns in `df2`.
- There is a column labelled `'C'` that has been added to `df1`, and a column labelled `'E'` that has been added to `df2`. These columns have been filled with `NaN`. This is because we performed an outer join on the column labels.
- None of the values inside the DataFrames have been altered.
- Note that the row labels are not aligned; `df2` has rows `3` and `4`, whereas `df1` does not. This is because we requested alignment on columns (`axis=1`).

What happens if we align on both rows and columns, but change the `join` parameter to `'right'`?

```
a1, a2 = df1.align(df2, join='right', axis=None)
print(a1)
print(a2)
```

> ```
>      A    B   C    D
> 2  9.0  7.0 NaN  6.0
> 3  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
> 4  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
>      A    B    C    D
> 2   10   20   30   40
> 3   60   70   80   90
> 4  600  700  800  900
> ```

Note that:

- Only the columns and rows that are found in the "right" dataframe (`df2`) are retained. Column `'E'` is no longer present. This is because we made a right join on both the column and row labels.
- Rows with labels `3` and `4` have been added to `df1`, filled with `Nan`. This is because we requested alignment on both rows and columns (`axis=None`).
- Row labels are now aligned as well as column labels.
- Again, note that none of the actual values within the dataframes have been altered.

Finally, let's have a look at the code in the question, with `join='inner'` and `axis=1`:

```
a1, a2 = df1.align(df2, join='inner', axis=1)
print(a1)
print(a2)
```

> ```
>    D  B  A
> 1  1  2  4
> 2  6  7  9
>      D    B    A
> 2   40   20   10
> 3   90   70   60
> 4  900  700  600
> ```

- Only column labels are aligned (`axis=1`).
- Only column labels that are present in both `df1` and `df2` are retained (`join='inner'`).

In summary, use `DataFrame.align()` when you want to make sure the arrangement of rows and/or columns is the same between two dataframes, without altering any of the data contained within the two dataframes.

Comment: Really nice elaborate answer

Comment: Really good answer. just one small correction in the explanation of second example of 'right' join -- "Rows with labels `3` and `4` have been added to df1, filled with `Nan`."

Answer (score 0):

In effect, `align()` does 2 things under the hood:

1. finds intersection / union of columns / indices
2. reindexes the columns/indices using the columns/indices found in 1.

In particular, in the OP's example, it is indexing two dataframes by their common columns. In other words, `df1, df2 = df1.align(df2, join='inner', axis=1)` is concise way to do the same thing as the following:

```py
cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
df1 = df1[cols]
df2 = df2[cols]
```

If `axis=0`, it would answer the question: [How to get the common index of two pandas dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48170867/19123103). In other words, the following two cases produce the same output:

```py
# case 1
df1, df2 = df1.align(df2, join='inner', axis=0)

# case 2
idx = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
df1 = df1.loc[idx]
df2 = df2.loc[idx]
```

An example to illustrate these points:

```py
from numpy.random import rand
import pandas as pd

# sample data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(rand(1000,20)).add_prefix('col').sample(n=800).sample(n=10, axis=1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rand(1000,20)).add_prefix('col').sample(n=40).sample(n=2, axis=1)


# aligning columns (case in OP)
a, b = df1.align(df2, join='inner', axis=1)

cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
a1 = df1[cols]
b1 = df2[cols]

a.equals(a1) and b.equals(b1)   # True


# aligning indices
a, b = df1.align(df2, join='inner', axis=0)

idx = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
a1 = df1.loc[idx]
b1 = df2.loc[idx]

a.equals(a1) and b.equals(b1)   # True
```

If you don't pass any axis, `align()` aligns on both index and columns.

---

For completeness, note that the behavior differs depending on what the join method is. The following is a table that shows the relationship between the reindexing operation mentioned above and `align` depending on join and axis values. For different values of `join` and `axis`, `df1.align(join=join, axis=axis)` is equivalent to the following code in each cell:

|  | `axis=1` | `axis=0` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `join='inner'` | ``` cols1 = df1.columns cols2 = df2.columns common = cols1.intersection(cols2) a = df1[common] b = df2[common] ``` | ``` idx1 = df1.index idx2 = df2.index common = idx1.intersection(idx2) a = df1.loc[common] b = df2.loc[common] ``` |
| `join='left'` | ``` a = df1 cols = df1.columns b = df2.reindex(columns=cols) ``` | ``` a = df1 b = df2.reindex(index=df1.index) ``` |
| `join='right'` | ``` cols = df2.columns a = df1.reindex(columns=cols) b = df2 ``` | ``` a = df1.reindex(index=df2.index) b = df2 ``` |
| `join='outer'` | ``` cols1 = df1.columns cols2 = df2.columns union = cols1.union(cols2) a = df1.reindex(columns=union) b = df2.reindex(columns=union) ``` | ``` idx = df1.index.union(df2.index) a = df1.reindex(index=idx) b = df2.reindex(index=idx) ``` |