# How to get common index of many dataframes and return their rows and dataframes they are from?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got 7 dataframes with same column names in python, but row indices are largely different and only few of the row indices match.

```
df1 
      col1 col2 col3
a     123  456  786 
b     121  454  787
c     111  444  777

df2 
      col1 col2 col3
d     13  46    86
e     11  44    87
c     11  44    77

df3 
      col1  col2  col3
d     1231  4567  1786
g     1214  4546  1787
h     1115  4445  1777
c     12    12    10
```

Answer should be:

```
newdf
newcol col1  col2  col3  dfcol
c      111   444   777   1
c      11    44    77    2
c      12    12    10    3
d      13    46    86    2
d      1231  4567  1786  3
```

It is similar to this [How to get the common index of two pandas dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170867/how-to-get-the-common-index-of-two-pandas-dataframes) but not exactly.

Comment: I'm confused by your output. `df1` doesn't have an index `d` the only common index among these 3 dataframes is `c`.

Comment: @ Henry Ecker: Common index can be in atleast two dfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

This is my beginner way of doing it.

```
import pandas as pd
```

Create dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'col1': [123, 121, 111],
  'col2': [456, 454, 444],
  'col3': [786, 787, 777],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'id': ['d', 'e', 'c'],
  'col1': [13, 46, 86],
  'col2': [11, 44, 87],
  'col3': [11, 44, 77],
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
  'id': ['d', 'g', 'h', 'c'],
  'col1': [1231, 1214, 1115, 12],
  'col2': [4567, 4546, 4445, 12],
  'col3': [1786, 1787, 1777, 10],
})
```

Create dataframe list as well as giving name to each dataframe

```
df_collection = [df1, df2, df3]
df1.name = 1
df2.name = 2
df3.name = 3
```

Create list:

```
id_col = [[df.loc[i, 'id'], df.loc[i, 'col1'], df.loc[i, 'col2'], df.loc[i, 'col3'], df.name] for df in df_collection for i in range(len(df))]
```

Construct new dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(id_col)
df.columns = ['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'df']
```

Remove rows with only 1 occurence:

```
new_df = df[df.groupby('id').id.transform('count') > 1].sort_values('id')
```

This will give us the following:

```
    id  col1   col2   col3  df
2   c   111    444    777   1
5   c   86     87     77    2
9   c   12     12     10    3
3   d   13     11     11    2
6   d   1231   4567   1786  3
```

Comment: This worked!
But I had to convert index column into a new column in all dfs. Thanks!